# What does this icon in the garage indicate?

Tags: rocket-league

In Rocket League, what does this icon in the garage mean?

[image: Rocket League Screnshot in Garage]

I have tried:

- [Steam question](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/0/541907867760348601/) which just says "some items are just available for some cars", which is not really helpful.
- I disagree with [this Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/3clune/what_does_this_garage_icon_mean/), because I think that should be an exclamation mark on the right side and it should disappear once the item was selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means those body types have some new decals which you haven't looked at yet. You'll need to select each body type, then look at the unlocked decal in order to get rid of it.

Comment: Or they can browse to the manage inventory section and mouse over them to hide the mark (especially useful for decals which you don't have the car for).